# Communication between Rails processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, websocket

Consider the tic-tac-toe game built with Nginx as a reverse proxy and having multiple Rails backends. Each client sets up a websocket connection with some Rails backends. If two clients playing a game are each connected to a different Rails backend, then a move sent to one backend needs to be routed to the other backend so it can be pushed on the other websocket as shown in the picture below.

In Rails what is the idiomatic way to communicate between two Rails backends?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation you should setup separate WebSocket server and connect both users and Rails servers to it. This way you will be able to handle all users from one server without worrying about sharding.

In case of high traffic you could also setup several WebSocket servers and implement some kind of queue or message bus between them that will propagate new messages - for example master server that will only handle propagating messages and slave servers that will be connected to it and sent all messages received from users to it. Please note that in such configuration master server should not handle connection from users and server only for propagation of messages between slaves.

Finaly, answering your last question directly, there is usually no need to contact between Rails servers directly - as opposite to WebSocket servers they serve on request-response basis so exchanging informations via database is enough in most cases. If you really need immediate change then solutions like [AMQP](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/amqp) should help.